# Conversion of ASPX to XAML

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, xaml

How can I write an .aspx file into a .xaml file of WPF?

how can I write or convert? Is there is any tool to convert?

Answer (score 0):

even if both are kind of XML, they are different. You can not really compare them neither convert.

Comment: Is there any tool for integrating .aspx file into .xaml file?

Comment: No, since its different technology.

Comment: Okay. Thank u so much.

Answer (score 0):

WinForms and WPF are different UI platforms.  You cannot directly convert your WinForms application to WPF as the controls, properties and methods are different in terms of classes, namespaces and syntax.  You have some work around solutions to achieve the convertion but 100 percent convertion is not possible. Please have look at the following links which will provide useful information on converting WinForms application to WPF.

[Windows Forms to Windows Presentation Foundation Converter](http://wf2wpf.codeplex.com/)

[WinForms -> XAML](http://rrelyea.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!167AD7A5AB58D5FE!1627.entry?sa=8496125)

[Guidance for migrating an app from Windows Forms to WPF?](http://blogs.windowsclient.net/rob_relyea/archive/2008/04/03/guidance-for-migrating-an-app-from-windows-forms-to-wpf.aspx)

[Creating the Same Program in Windows Forms and WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/winforms2wpf.aspx?display=Print)